# setting up multiple GPU's to mine

Tags: gpu-mining

I'm new to mining XMR, and mining in general. I'm currently using a Evga GTX760 Superclocked 2 gig card and am picking up a gtx 750ti tonight. For pretty cheap but I know I don't have it set up right for the 760. Because "GPU #0: Warning: block count 40 is not a multiple of SMX count 6." how do I fix this in the batch? As well how do I add the new card in to the batch file? I'm using the Nanopool TSIV-XMR CCminer and for the life of me cant find the information or I'm just not connecting the dots. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, rolling back my drivers appeared to fix this. [Nvidia Driver Rollback](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/driver_rollback.html)